# Typescript Angular accessing parameter that should be delivered by service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have problem when I access variable, that should be resolved by service. If I use this variable directly with angular in html there is no problem, but when I want to use it in method I become nothing. Service is working fine and it is http rest service call.
Here's Controller:

```
///<reference path='../domain/DocumentEntity.ts' />
///<reference path='../_app.ts'/>
module domain {
import DataAccessService = domain.DataAccessService;
import IDocument = domain.IDocument;
import DocumentEntity = domain.DocumentEntity;
import IEntity = domain.IEntity;
import Structure = domain.Structure;

interface IDocListController {
    response: IEntity;
    locations: IEntity;
    structures: IStructure[];
}


export class DocController implements IDocListController {
    title: string;
    response: domain.IEntity;
    locations: domain.IEntity;
    structures: IStructure[];
    static $inject = ["DataAccessService", "$scope"];

    constructor(private dataAccessService: DataAccessService, $scope) {
        this.title = "Document Listing";
        //test
        var documentResource = dataAccessService.getDataResource();
        documentResource.query((data: domain.IEntity) => {
            this.response = data;
        });
        $scope.vm = this;
        console.log($scope.vm);
        if (!this.response || !this.response.folders.length) {
            console.log("NO RESPONSE RETURNING NOTHING");
            return;
        }
        this.structures = this.createFolderStructure(this.response.folders,     4);
        console.log(this.structures);

    }

    createFolderStructure(folders: IFolder[], depth: number): IStructure[] {
        var structures: Structure[] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
            let str: Structure = new Structure();
            str.id = folders[i].id.toPrecision();
            str.isFolder = true;
            str.name = folders[i].name;
            str.structures = this.createFolderStructure(folders, depth - 1);
            structures.push(str);
        }
        console.log(structures);
        return structures;
    };
}
```

And the Service looks like this:

```
  /// <reference path='../_app.ts' />
  module domain {
 import DocumentEntity = domain.DocumentEntity;

export interface IDataAccessService {
    getDataResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IEntityResource>;
}

export interface IEntityResource extends ng.resource.IResource<domain.Entity> {
}

export class DataAccessService implements IDataAccessService {
    //minification protection
    static $inject = ["$resource"]

    constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        console.log("DataAccessService Constructor");
    }

    getDataResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IEntityResource> {
        console.log("REST CALL");
        return this.$resource("http://localhost:8080/services/name/:searchId/documents/", {searchId: "12345678"}, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            }
        });
    }
}

angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced part in the constructor of controller with $promise.then construct like this:

```
 documentResource.query((data: domain.IEntity) => {
            this.response = data;
        }).$promise.then((data)=> {
                if (this.response.folders) {
                    this.structures  = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.response.folders.length; i++) {
                        if(this.response.folders){
                        Array.prototype.push.apply(this.structures,this.createFolderStructure(this.response.folders, 4));
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(this.structures);
                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you solved the problem in a correct way,I want to point out the real issue. The real problem was you haven't pass query parameter in your query request which is 1st parameter. You should pass 1st parameter as `{}` to `query` function thereafter we can pass success & error callbacks respectively 2nd & 3rd.

**Code**

```
var documentResource = dataAccessService.getDataResource();
documentResource.query({}, //1st parameter should pass as a blank
   (data: domain.IEntity) => {
     this.response = data;
   }
);
```

---

Though another way is you can directly assign `$resource` promise object to desired variable so when promise get resolved API will unwrapped that promise and assign received data to `this.response`.

```
this.response  = dataAccessService.getDataResource();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the parameter I had in my source code, but I deleted it when editing the real URL for the post here. I will edit my post.